# Cycles material looks different despite same node setup

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, transparency

I am trying to make a translucent tape material, but for the life of me, I can't get them to look similar.

[image]

The tape of the right is what I want it to look like, but somehow, the tape on the left turns out darker despite having the same node setup!

Any help and advice will be appreciated.

Current node setup:

[image]

Blend file with packed textures: https://pasteall.org/blend/79bec9f1914f4c4fac8d6f21d3da576f

Thank you!

***edit:

This is what happen when I copy a tape across. I suspect that the lighting causes the difference in tones. Is there anyway to improve my material node setup to ensure consistency?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). The color behind the right one is a lot darker. Also, is it aligned right to the photo to avoid shadows?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Yes, the tape are aligned right to the photos... 

If we based the part of the tape on the wall, the right tape clearly looks much lighter than the left!